# Operador ?: não funciona

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou fazendo o `union`, em um dos `select` eu preciso fazer uma condição para aparecer da forma correta. Para não ficar aparecendo valores em branco.

Tentei fazendo desta forma:

```
      Documento = (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal != null ? "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal : null +
         c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos != null ? " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos : null).Trim()
```

Porém não funciona como o esperado, aqui é a parte completa do código:

```
 var FR = db.FaturaContasReceber.Include(c => c.FaturaContasReceberP).Where(c => c.Quitado == true && c.Caixa == false && c.BancoId == id).Select(c => new BancoList
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Data = c.DataPagamento,
            Valor = c.Total,
            Tipo = "C",
            Documento = (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal != null ? "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal : null +
         c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos != null ? " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos : null).Trim()
        }).ToList();
```

Como resolver, eu preciso que ele apareça o campo se ele tiver preenchimento, pode ocorrer de só um dos dois ser preenchido, ou dos dois.

Comment: Que eu saiba, o C# não aceita ponto de interrogação dentro do `if`, talvez tenha algum outro caractere especial que o substitua

Comment: Desculpe, editei a pergunta, não estou utilizando o `if`

Comment: tenta colocar a operação entre parênteses, tipo `("Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal)`.. o c# pode tá se perdendo com os sinais

Comment: @rLinhares ele só aparece os valores de NFSe, se mesmo o NFe não sendo `null` ele não aparece, e quando somente o NFe possui valor, o `Documento` fica vazio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esta nessa parte `Fiscal : null + c.FaturaContasReceberP`

Tente fazer desse jeito, separando as lógicas entre parênteses.

```
Documento = (
    (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal != null ? "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal : "") +
    (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos != null ? " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos : "")
).Trim()
```

Comment: Retorna o seguinte erro:  Tipo de expressão condicional não pode ser determinado porque não há conversão implícita entre "string" e "char"

Comment: @marianac_costa altere as plicas por aspas

Comment: Deu certinho, rs @vik nem tinha me atentado a este detalhe. Obrigado.

Comment: Editei a resposta com a correção, vlw

Answer (score 3):

Outra solução:

```
Documento = (c.FaturaContasReceberP?.NotaFiscal?.ToString().Insert(0, "Fat. NFSe: ") + c.FaturaContasReceberP?.NotaFiscalProdutos?.ToString().Insert(0, " NFe: ")).Trim();
```

Caso o tipo de `NotaFiscal` e `NotaFiscalProdutos` seja `string`, pode excluir `.ToString()`

### [?. Operadores nulos condicionais](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

Testa o valor do operando esquerdo para nulo antes de executar um acesso de membro (?.) ou uma operação de índice (?[]); retorna null se o operando esquerdo é avaliado como null.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta colocar parenteses para isolar o operador ternário interno:

```
Documento = (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal != null ? 
                "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal : 
                (null + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos != null ? 
                    " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos : 
                    null
                )
            ).Trim();
```

[Editado] Tenta validar c.FaturaContasReceberP é nulo:

```
Documento = (c.FaturaContasReceberP != null ? (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal != null ? 
                "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal.Trim() : 
                (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos != null ? 
                    "NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos.Trim() : 
                    ""
                )
            ) : "");
```

Comment: Também não funciona, só mostra o primeiro que é NFSe mesmo o NFe não sendo null não aparece, e se somente o NFe tem o valor, ele não aparece nada.

Comment: Ajustei validando se c.FaturaContasReceberP é nulo. Se ainda não funcionar, posta o erro que tá aparecendo na depuração.